# Run Makefile + Ant Buildfile inside Maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, ant, groovy, makefile, maven-plugin

I've checked out jquery + jquery-ui from GitHub into my `src/main/webapp/resources/js` folder.

Now I would like to do the minifying stuff by pom.xml
([jquery uses a Makefile](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/Makefile) - [jquery-ui uses an Ant buildfile](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/build/build.xml))

Is it possible to do this?
I just thought about a [Groovy Script inside pom.xml](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code#ExecutingGroovyCode-ExecuteanInlineGroovyScript)

Is it the clean/popular way to do this?
And can anyone give an example,
because I'm totally new to Groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running Ant targets consider to use [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/). For invoking `make` commands I suggest to look to [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/)

Comment: Is it possible to set a workingDirectory for [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) as well to run build.xml from within the specified path to avoid wrong behavior?

Comment: I don't know. Probably this is a subject for another question.